# Eclipse Neon.3 / error dialog window pops up after clicking on WildFly @ Servers-Tab

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm asking for your help:

Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3):

Everytime when I click in the Servers-Tab on my WildFly 10 Server I get this error dialog window, but there are no errors in the console-output. Also deploying and all other functions in Eclipse behave fine.

But how to get rid of this error dialog popup?:

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/spotify/docker/client/DefaultDockerClient.copyContainer(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/io/InputStream; @43: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/TextNode' (current frame, stack[2]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @43
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/spotify/docker/client/DefaultDockerClient', 'java/lang/String', 'java/lang/String', 'javax/ws/rs/client/WebTarget', 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/JsonNodeFactory' }
    stack: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ObjectNode', 'java/lang/String', 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/TextNode' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab7 005a 1268 b900 5602 002b b900 5602
    0x0000010: 0012 bfb9 0056 0200 4eb2 00c0 3a04 1904
    0x0000020: b600 c112 c219 042c b600 c3b6 00c4 3a05
    0x0000030: 2a12 6112 bd2d 2d04 bd00 5d59 03b2 00be
    0x0000040: 53b9 005f 0200 1905 b800 63b7 0064 c000
    0x0000050: bdb0
```

I don't use Docker and Jackson.

I've tried 1000 things including deleting / rebuilding the entry for the WildFly-Server, but all in vain ...

I appreciate your help.

Regards
Joe

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an open bug in Eclipse : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=506051

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Yes, I've seen this entry - it is nearly 1 year old so I could not believe that it is still open ...

Comment: Yep, I had "solve" the issue from my Eclipse by removing all the plug-in associated to AngularJS, Typescript, Tern and NodeJS. I still don't know which one had carry the bug with him.

Comment: I've not installed the tools you have written. But it sounds good that you've found a solution. I'll continue to search for a solution too. Thank you.